# How to add username in admin page who logged in when withdrawing an amount?

Tags: python, html, django

I have made a `form` to give an option for user to withdraw money. That data is saving in admin page but the problem is I have `owner` variable also, which I want that as the amount data is going to be saved in admin page the `owner` username should also be saved in admin, which shows who is desiring this amount?

**models.py**

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
class WithdrawPayment(models.Model):
    payment = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Withdraw Payment'
```

**views.py**

```
@login_required
def withdraw(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = WithdrawBalance(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            messages.success(request, f'Your request has been submitted.')
            return redirect('index')
    else:
        form = WithdrawBalance()
    context = {'form': form}
    return render(request, 'nextone/withdraw.html', context)
```

**forms.py**

```
class WithdrawBalance(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = WithdrawPayment
        fields = ['payment']
```

Comment: Could you also give the WithdrawPayment-model?

Comment: I have updated it now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this:

```
@login_required
def withdraw(request):
    form_class = WithdrawBalanceForm
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = form_class(request.POST)
            obj = form.save(commit=False)
            obj.owner = request.user
            obj.save()
            messages.success(request, f'Your request has been submitted.')
            return redirect('index')
    else:
        form = form_class()
    context = {'form': form}
    return render(request, 'nextone/withdraw.html', context)

class WithdrawBalanceForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = WithdrawPayment
        fields = ['payment']
```